# mysql compare column with count()

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables. One for Customers and another for Rooms.
What I want to retrieve the rooms using mysql with the following requirements..

1. the number of customers in a specific room is less than the head from the rooms table
2. the room is not in the customers table

you may check out this paste
http://pastebin.com/WgTtkQvD

as you can see only room 1 is not in the expected result because its 'head' and the total customers in that room is equal

room 2 has 3 customers which is less than the 'head' of room 2

rooms 3 and 4 are in the expected result because no one has 'occupied it yet

Comment: What does 'head' mean in this ?

Comment: the maximum customers in a specific room

Comment: in the customers table there is one customer who is using room 1. in the rooms table the 'head' (maximum customers) is equal to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT   Rooms.id AS room_id,
         COUNT(Customer.id) AS occupied,
         Rooms.head AS total_head,
         Rooms.head - COUNT(Customer.id) AS remaining_head
FROM     Rooms LEFT JOIN Customer ON Customer.room_id = Rooms.id
GROUP BY Rooms.id
HAVING   remaining_head > 0
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45a59/1/0).

Comment: can you explain me how group by and having worked? also got confused with the left join part .thanks :D

Comment: @kapitanluffy: Read [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to understand a `LEFT JOIN`.  `GROUP BY Rooms.id` aggregates all of the records with the same value in `Rooms.id` into a single record (so the `COUNT()` function is performed over each such group).  `HAVING` then filters the resulting groups, much like `WHERE` filters records before any grouping is performed.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
SELECT r.id, COUNT(c.id), r.head, r.head - COUNT(c.id) FROM Rooms AS r LEFT JOIN Customer AS c ON r.id = c.room_id WHERE r.head <= COUNT(c.id) GROUP BY r.id
```

I didn't fully understand your question and I haven't actually tried this on a real DB, so there may be some glitches to sort out. Comment it any more questions arise.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works

```
select r.id,c.occ_cnt as occupied,r.head as total_head,r.head - c.occ_cnt as       remaining_head
from room r,
(
select room_id,count(id) as occ_cnt
from customer
group by room_id
) c
where r.id = c.room_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    r.id,coalesce(ct.counting,0) as occupied,r.head as total_head,
    r.head-coalesce(ct.counting,0)  as remaining_head
from
    rooms as r left join
(
    select room_id,count(id) as counting from customer as ct 
    group by room_id
) as ct on r.id=ct.room_id
where r.head-coalesce(ct.counting,0)>0
```